# What should I do if I want to change my track for Master's degree that is completely different from Bachelor's?

Tags: masters, united-states, undergraduate, data, major

What should I do if I want to change my track for Master's degree that is completely different from Bachelor's subject in USA (non-US resident)? Currently, I am pursuing bachelor's degree in Film and Media studies but I want to change my subject to continue with different master's.

Comment: Change to what, generally or specifically? Still in the arts? And is your bachelors from a US institution or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will likely depend on whether you have required coursework to be admitted into the master's program you have in mind.  If you'd like to move from film and media to something very different, like computer science or physics, it's likely you're going to need to start over with a second bachelor's first (though you may get credit for some of the work you did on the first one).  But if you want to move to something where there's more overlap, say, from film and media to communications, you might be able to do that directly.  If it's only a small difference, perhaps you could make it up as non-matriculated student somewhere, taking just the courses you need. What I would do is research the program(s) you're interested in to see if you have credentials they expect and, if you don't, what your options are to fix it.

Comment: That's a very useful insight! Thank you for your suggestion!